# How to populate drop down list in Excel

Tags: excel, csv

I am currently using CSV file to populate the data. The users download that CSV file, edit and upload the file. There are a lot of things that could go wrong if I let the users type in. So, I was wondering if there is a way to populate drop-down fields by using either CSV or XLS or any other format. Instead of typing, the users can select from the drop-down.

P.S. Not sure if this is important to know, but I am using NodeJS to populate the data into CSV files.

Comment: yes. This is called "Data Validation" in excel. You define which cells are subject to Data Validation and you defined how it's validated. A list causes a drop down in the cell of allowed values.

Comment: @JNevill, yes, but how can I populate them through the code?

Comment: 1. Put the values you want in the cells that drive the validation via code `Range("A1").Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
        xlBetween, Formula1:="a,b,c,d"`. 2. Add an ActiveX Combo Box like `ActiveSheet.OLEObjects.Add(ClassType:="Forms.ComboBox.1", Link:=False, _
        DisplayAsIcon:=False, Left:=253.5, Top:=33.75, Width:=122.25, Height _
        :=9)` and populate it. 3. Add an excel form combo box and link it with cells `ActiveSheet.DropDowns.Add(292.5, 108, 105.75, 62.25)`. There's a lot of ways to solve this one and it depends on your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Say we start with:

[image]

This sample macro:

```
Sub ImportFiles()
   Dim j As Long, k As Long

    Close #1
    Open "C:\Users\Garys\Desktop\shop.csv" For Input As #1
    j = 1
     Do While Not EOF(1)
            Line Input #1, TextLine
            ary = Split(TextLine, ",")
            k = 1
            For Each a In ary
               Cells(j, k) = a
               k = k + 1
            Next a
            j = j + 1
    Loop
    Close #1


    With Columns("B:B").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
            xlBetween, Formula1:="yes,no"
            .IgnoreBlank = True
            .InCellDropdown = True
            .InputTitle = ""
            .ErrorTitle = ""
            .InputMessage = ""
            .ErrorMessage = ""
            .ShowInput = True
            .ShowError = True
        End With
End Sub
```

Will inport the *.csv* and setup data validation on column **B**

Answer (score 0):

Use a hidden sheet inside your Excel file. Instead of using the CSV, populate the hidden sheet with same data.

On another sheet, let the user to enter data that will be picked up from the hidden sheet, using the drop-down. In order to set the drop-down use **Data Validation** (Data tab, Data Validation). Choose **List** and select as **Source** the values from the hidden sheet. For convenience, you can temporarily unhide the hidden sheet.